# How does AMP determine a user's physical location?

Tags: location, verification

New to AMP pages (they were suggested by Google Adsense). On the learning curve. I need to use AMP for Consent Management for EAA and UK users.

It looks like AMP determines a user's physical location - what does it use?
Do VPNs change things?
What if the user signs-up on my site while in a different country from their normal residence?

Haven't been able to find any results online to this question. Relevant links would be very welcome.